# Editing an Illustrator file placed in an Illustrator file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, file-placing

I am collating several logos into an **Illustrator** **Artboard**.

Obviously, to be efficient and productive, I placed them the fastest way I know - by dragging the files from my OS to the **Illustrator** document window.

When I do so, the placed logos (in **.ai** format) appear in a box, and the edges of the shapes cannot seem to be edited/selected.

**After placing Illustrator files in an Illustrator file, how do I enable editing of the placed files in the final document?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>By default, Illustrator loads it in as a raster object link of the Illustrator file, to fix this.</del>

I was wrong, thanks [@Scott](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115877/editing-an-illustrator-file-placed-in-an-illustrator-file#comment172477_115878) for this great insight: (paraphrased)

> It loads in the PDF preview which technically − can be referred to as a "raster preview". It links to the *vector data* in the linked .ai file.
>
> It's closer to a symbol in how it's one object which could be expanded, than it is to a raster image link (which can't be expanded).

---

You have to embed it in and then;

Ungroup and release all the boatloads of clipping masks and groups that come with it when dragged in.

- Select all and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> a few times to ungroup everything.
- Select all and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> a few times to release all the clipping masks.

---

Here's a GIF:

[image: GIF showing the steps]
<sup>(Notice how the transparency get's lost, not sure why/how to fix that)</sup>

Comment: The files have already been placed in the document, as linked files

Comment: @MicroMachine yeh, but it places them in as a linked raster preview to the actual ai file, embedding it will **embed** it as vectors.

Comment: How is embedding different than placing? I don't know a "embed" function, only place. I can seem to zoom in infinitely on the placed files, they do not seem to be pixels

Comment: Unsure, once the file is *placed* it still needs to be embedded (placing a file only places a "link" with a preview to the file)

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say *"... loads it in as a raster object link ..."*. Really it loads the PDF preview which I guess *technically* can be referred to as a "raster preview". But the reality is, it links to the vector data in the linked ai file. It's closer to a *symbol* in how it's one object which *could be expanded*, than it is to a raster image link (which can't be expanded). Semantics pretty much, I'm aware. +1.

Comment: It vector just not editable. sincre it will work even if the pdf has no preview or indeed without resolution limits. I wouldnt embed it though i wouldjust open the original file then it uodates all links.